# Select inside another select

Tags: sparql

I have the following query where I'm trying to use the id of an element from one graph to retrieve some values in another graph. However this doesn't work:

```sql
select * from <mygraph2#> where {
  ?s ?p ?id in {select ?id from <mygraph1#> where { ?id ?t "MyService" }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't select *from* a subselect.  You just execute the sub-select, and it provides some variables to the enclosing query.  I'm not sure where you found an example like what you showed in the question.  It's not what any of the examples in the standard (see [Section 12, Subqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#subqueries)) look like. Your query would be something like this (note that this isn't actually legal, since you can't use FROM in subqueries):

```sql
select * from <mygraph2#> where {
  ?s ?p ?id
  { select ?id from <mygraph1#>
    where { ?id ?t "MyService" } }
}
```

However, the the graphs that you're selecting from are available as named graphs in the dataset, there's no real need for the sub-select here.  You can just do

```sql
select * where {
  graph <mygraph2#> { ?s ?p ?id }
  graph <mygraph1#> { ?id ?t "MyService" }
}
```

Comment: A side note, `FROM` is valid only in the outermost query.

Comment: @JindřichMynarz good catch! I added a note in the answer about that